# Как сгененрировать "Реляционную схему базы данных" в mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, ubuntu, mysql-workbench

Пытаюсь выявить связи в существующей системе CMS для интеграции ее в стороннее решение, столкнулся с проблемой труднодоступности выстраивания связей в ACL.
В связи с чем хочу узнать, как получить реляционную схему таблиц для того, чтобы быстрее ориентироваться и интегрировать данную систему.
Пока нашел только вот это
https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/design/

Но там не слова о генерации  на основе уже существующей базы, чтобы можно было удобнее всего отсмотреть связи.

Comment: *там не слова о генерации на основе уже существующей базы, чтобы можно было удобнее всего отсмотреть связи.* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-reverse-engineer-live.html

Comment: Печаль беда, а вообще был у кого-то подобный опыт?

Comment: В справке описывается процесс построения EER-диаграммы для учебной БД sakila. Не вижу оснований полагать, что для другой БД тот же процесс не сработает...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для построения диаграммы БД MySQL можно использовать инструмент [dbForgeStudio for MySQL](https://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/mysql/studio/download.html).

1) Подключаемся к БД;

2) Выбираем меню "База данных" -> "Диаграмма БД"

[image: my]

3) Перетаскиваем БД в рабочее поле диаграммы

Решение под Windows, но [здесь](http://blog.devart.com/dbforge-studio-mysql-on-linux-operating-systems.html) есть вариант запуска и в Linux.

Еще есть инструмент [SchemaSpy](https://priyankacool10.wordpress.com/2012/10/13/how-to-install-schemaspy-for-a-database-in-ubuntu-12-04/). [Здесь](https://priyankacool10.wordpress.com/2012/10/13/how-to-install-schemaspy-for-a-database-in-ubuntu-12-04/) есть описание использования в Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

В MySQL WorkBench есть вкладка Database - Reverse Engineering (ctrl+R). 
Запускаешь, выбираешь нужную базу и "далее" -> "далее"...